# While Not Loop for empty list in python

Tags: python, while-loop, empty-list

I am making a request to a server... for whatever reason (beyond my comprehension), the server will give me a status code of 200, but when I use Beautiful Soup to grab a list from the html, nothing is returned. It only happens on the first page of pagination.

To get around a known bug, I have to loop until the list is not empty.

This works, but it's clunky. Is there a better way to do this? Knowing that I have to force the request until the list contains an item.

```
# look for attractions
attraction_list = soup.find_all(attrs={'class': 'listing_title'})
while not attraction_list:
    print('the list is empty')
    try:
        t = requests.Session()
        t.cookies.set_policy(BlockAll)
        page2 = t.get(search_url)
        print(page2.status_code)
        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(page2.content, 'html.parser')
        attraction_list = soup2.find_all(attrs={'class': 'listing_title'}) 
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Was there a reason why this was voted down? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this.

```
attraction_list = soup.find_all(attrs={'class': 'listing_title'})
while not attraction_list:
    print('the list is empty')
    for q in range(0, 4):
        try:
            t = requests.Session()
            t.cookies.set_policy(BlockAll)
            page2 = t.get(search_url)
            print(page2.status_code)
            soup2 = BeautifulSoup(page2.content, 'html.parser')
            attraction_list = soup2.find_all(attrs={'class': 'listing_title'})
        except Exception as str_error:
            print('FAILED TO FIND ATTRACTIONS')
            time.sleep(3)
            continue
        else:
            break
```

It'll try 4 times to get that pull the attractions, if `attractions_list` ends up with a valid list, it breaks. Good enough.